I can't subtract two TimeMark in my Kotlin program in Android Studio
I'm currently facing a problem in Android Studio.
I've been trying to subtract two Time Mark, but I get the following  error:
"Using 'minus(TimeMark): Duration' is an error. Subtracting one TimeMark from another is not a well defined operation because these time marks could have been obtained from the different time sources."
I've simplified my code to understand what was wrong, searched on Google and Bing but there was no mention of a similar problem.
Here the code
        @OptIn(ExperimentalTime::class)
        val timeSource = TimeSource.Monotonic
        val startTime = timeSource.markNow() 
        processing()
        val endTime = timeSource.markNow() 
        val duration : Duration = endTime-startTime

Could you help me with this matter? Your help would be very much appreciated!
I've checked the current version of Kotlin and it's the version 1.9.0 so it was supposed to work.
Here are the code from the gradle scripts :
Gradle properties:
#gralde build config
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608M

#use androidX
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true

#å»æèµæºéå¤æ£æ¥
android.disableResourceValidation=true
android.enableJetifier=true

#build config
ANDROID_MIN_SDK_VERSION=23
ANDROID_TARGET_SDK_VERSION=33
ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK_VERSION=33
KOTLIN_VERSION = 1.7.21
#NDK_VERSION = 21.3.6528147

#msdk api key
AIRCRAFT_API_KEY = 9ba33182383ce52b038e83cc

#map key
AMAP_API_KEY = ENTER YOUR AMAP API KEY
GMAP_API_KEY =  ENTER YOUR Google Map API KEY
MAPLIBRE_TOKEN = "ENTER YOUR  MapLibre TOKEN"


#ç­¾åä¿¡æ¯ï¼ä¸´æ¶æä»¶ï¼æµè¯ç¨
STORE_FILE = ../../android-sdk-v5-as/msdkkeystore.jks
STORE_PASSWORD = 123456
KEY_ALIAS = msdkkeystore
KEY_PASSWORD = 123456

#maven
KOTLIN_MAVEN = https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap
REPO_MAVEN2 = https://repo1.maven.org/maven2
JITPACK_MAVEN_URL = https://jitpack.io

build.gradle:
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
apply from: rootProject.file('dependencies.gradle')

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }
        maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap' }
    }

    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$KOTLIN_VERSION"
    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url REPO_MAVEN2
        }
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url KOTLIN_MAVEN
        }
        maven { url JITPACK_MAVEN_URL }
        repositories {
            flatDir {
                dirs new File(rootProject.projectDir.getAbsolutePath() + '/libs')
            }
        }
    }
}

I've already imported the library linked to all the time functions import kotlin.time.*

You seem to to use a quite old version where this wasn't fixed yet, from when TimeSource was still experimental as your annotation suggests. Please middle-click on TimeSource and hover over the opened tab in the tab bar. There should be a version displayed in the popup. What is it? Also, please [edit] your question and provide your dependencies (version catalog / gradle files).

Thanks for your reply. When I hover over the opened tab (TimeSource.kt) I can see that the version is 1.7.21.

Finally, I was able to fix the problem. You were right, I wasn't using the right Kotlin version so what I did was to modify gradle.properties and put the right Kotlin version
KOTLIN_VERSION = 1.9.10 instead of 1.7.21. Thanks a lot for your help

Glad you could fix that. But please take a look at your latest edit where you seem to have included several passwords and API keys from your build configuration. Make sure that doesn't pose a security problem. Maybe you need to change them since they are now public.
